# Get data from object php laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

Hi guys I need a bit of help here,

My variable `$a` has value `[{"id":"[1, 2, 3]"}]` of type `object`, now from this I want the first `id` i.e. in this case I want `1`. How can I fetch ut from variable `$a`?

When I var_dump it prints as below

```
class Illuminate\Support\Collection#1230 (1) {
  protected $items =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    class stdClass#1221 (1) {
      public $a =>
      string(9) "[1, 2, 3]"
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: try `($a[0])->id[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the `class` of `$a` ?
Is it an extend of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` ?

Maybe this :

```php
$firstId = current($a->id);
```

---

EDIT :

I don't see the `id` on your dump.

```
current(json_decode($a->first()->id))
```

or

```
current(json_decode($a->first()->a))
```

Comment: I have updated the question Can you check this once

Comment: Thanks a lot. You save my day!

Answer (score 0):

Can you access ?

```
echo $a->id; // outputs strings "[1,2,3]"
```

if yes, then just decode it by using json_decode

```
$array = json_decode($a->id);
$firstElement = current($array);
```